# how to include filename in first column of existing csv file

Tags: unix, awk

I have existing csv file.I want to modify the csv file and include filename in first column of the file.

```
Example
file.csv

1,love,anger

Modified csv
file.csv
file.csv,1,love,anger
```

Can we do it using  one liner in awk or unix

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

another one

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' file
```

Comment: Nice, shorter than my variant. You can even remove `-F,`

Answer (score 0):

It's just as simple as: `awk '{if($0) printf("%s,%s\n", FILENAME, $0); else print FILENAME;}' file.csv`

where file.csv is input file name.

UPD.: I modified command adding condition to correctly deal with empty lines